# Converting a Float to RGB data in opencv

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, colors

I have a 2D vector of float values that I need to create an image from it.

The code that I have is as follows:

```
inline cv::Mat ConvertToMat(vector<vector<float>> inputData)
{
    static int MAXGREY = 255;
    static int MAXRANGE = 255;
    int Red, Blue, Green;
    float maxValue = GetMaxValue(inputData); // find max value in input data
    cv::Mat output(inputData.getXSize(), inputData.getXSize(), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar::all(0));
    // if the max value is equal to or less than 0, no data in the vector to convert.
    if (maxValue > 0)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < inputData.size(); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < inputData[x].size(); y++)
            {
                auto Value = inputData[x][y];
                Green = 0;
                Red = Value * 255 / maxValue;
                Blue = (maxValue - Value) * 255 / maxValue;
                cv::Vec3b xyzBuffer;
                xyzBuffer[0] = Blue;
                xyzBuffer[1] = Red;
                xyzBuffer[2] = Green;
                output.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y) = xyzBuffer;
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

but this method doesn't generate suitable results when there is a pixel with a very high value and a lot of pixels with small values, all small values can not be seen on the output.
for example, lets look this set of data for input:

```
int main()
{
    vector<vector<float>> inputData =
    {
        {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
        {1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5},
        {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
        {1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5},
        {1,2,3,4,2000,6,7,8,9,10},
        {1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5},
        {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
        {1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5},
        {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
        {1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5}
    };
    cv::Mat image=ConvertToMat(inputData);
    cv::imwrite("c://tmp//myimage.jpg", image);
    return 0;
}
```

The generated out is as follow (the value of each pixel is shown on the pixel):
[image]

Since we have 3X byte data for colour, we should have enough dynamic range to show the data for each pixel in a different colour. but the above algorithm converts the value of 1 and 2 and 3 into the same colour (254,0,0).

How can I convert a float into three different colours so I can see all pixels with a different colour suitable for visual inspection (so each pixel which is near to the other has similar colour but not the same colour)?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. It's appropriately marked as an algorithm question, and writing the code comes after deciding what it should do.

Comment: If you don't care about the distance between values, I'd simply give each unique value (or whatever range of values you want) in the image a distinct index (grayscale value). Then you can display the grayscale image with an appropriate [colormap](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html).